# Cursor move to left when I press right arrow key on the keyboard in textfield flutter app

Tags: flutter, textfield, right-to-left

I have a android and web application in flutter .I am wondered why when I press right arrow key in text field ,the cursor move to left .my language is Arabic and I set localisation in my app rightly and also I set textdirection for my textfield as RTL value but it don't work rightly.
Thanks in advance for your help